# Accessing Model in razor html from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing entity framework mvc web app. 
I have this razor syntax html:

```
@section Scripts
{
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#world-map').vectorMap({
                map: 'world_mill',
                    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
                    hoverColor: false,
                    markerStyle: {
                        initial: {
                            fill: '#F8E23B',
                            stroke: '#383f47'
                        }
                    },
                    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
         //I want this to be done like described not code created
                    markers: [
                      { latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City' },
                      { latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco' },
                      { latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru' }
                    ]
                });
            });

</script>
}
```

What i want is to load this markers not from java script code, i want to load them using model which is accessible in razor html. I want to do something like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    //Model.latitude, Model.longitude, Model.name create markers for map and    load them
}
```

Is this even possible? Can I write another function for creating Markers?
I found some answers here but none was helpful. 
Any help appritiated.

Comment: You could create view model, construct your JSON for markers in controller and return it in some property. Then you would need to assign this value like `markers: @Model.Markers`.

Comment: `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` converts you model to a javascript array of objects

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you please write an exapmle of how could I use it in java script function?

Comment: If you just add the above code (before `$('#world-map').vectorMap({`) and then use `markers: model,` it will generate `markers: [ { latitude: xx, longitude: yy, name: zz }, { .... }]` (where `xx`, `yy` and `zz` are the values of your properties - one object for each item in you collection)

Comment: If you actually need it to be `{ latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City' }` then your model properties would need to be `float[] latLng` and `string name` (not familiar with vectorMap, so not sure what formats it will accept)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! Your post helped me.